# getline() reaches end of file when reading UTF-8 emoji character

Tags: c++, locale, emoji, getline, wstring

I'm writing a C++ program that processes large delimited files.

I have a UTF-8 csv file that contains a row with the (*emoji?*) character . It looks something like this:

```
123,"james","piotrj","1996-01-28"
```

When I call `getline()` on this row, it reads up to the emoji and then stops. So the resulting string from `getline()` is `123,"james","piotrj`. I'm not sure exactly why it is happening. If I had to guess, I'm using locale improperly and this emoji (*or part of it*) is being read as an `EOF`.

I would like to read this row in as is, do some string operations, and then write it out to another file.

I have some example code here:

```
locale loc("en_US.UTF8");
wifstream inFile;
inFile.imbue(loc);
inFile.open("MyFile.csv");
if(inFile.is_open()){
  wstring str;
  if (getline(inFile, str)) {
    wcout << str << endl;
  }
  if (getline(inFile, str)) {
    wcout << str << endl;
  }
  inFile.close();
}
```

The output of this code is : `123,"james","piotrj`. The second if statements body does not execute because the second `getline()` did not grab anything.

To try some things, I changed the locale to this:

```
locale loc = locale();
```

The name of the locale is "C" and that will get the entire line. The output of this program is: `123,"james","piotrj≡ƒîƒ","1996-01-28"`. This is a step in the right direction, but without the proper locale the wstring will not store it properly. In my program I do some individual character checking to see if the string could be represented in ANSI, thus I would really like the wstring to have that emoji as one character.

Comment: Could you show a file content as a char array of hex values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using libc++. Wide streams in this implementation *do not support UTF-8 at all*.

Should you use libstdc++ instead, your program would work, except you would get transliterated text on the output. I am getting

```
123,"james","piotrj?","1996-01-28"
```

That's because the locale is *not* imbued in `wcout`. To get normal text, you would need to do either

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
wcout.imbue(loc);
```

(you cannot imbue a locale in a standard stream if it is synched with stdio)

or, alternatively,

```
locale::global(loc);
```

Then your program would fully work.

If you are tied to libc++, your only alternative is to use narrow character streams.

Edit: with MSVC this code doesn't work either. Don't know why Microsoft claims UTF-8 support in newer versions of Windows, apparently it's not there at all. On Windows one can install gcc (one of several flavours, I recommend the UCRT flavour available with MSYS2). I cannot guarantee it will work though because ultimately the control flow passes through Microsoft runtime libraries. The proper solution is to *never, ever* use any `wchar_t` APIs except for calling specific WinAPI functions that require `wchar_t`. Use narrow characters, read UTF-8 from your file, store and manipulate strings as UTF-8, output them as UTF-8. I have tested this code converted to narrow characters with MSVC, and it works as expected for me.

Comment: Thank you!

I was originally developing this on windows using Visual Studio. I switched to WSL and used libstdc++ and it worked! With that though, I would really like my program to be a windows executable. Is there a way to use libstdc++ on Visual studio that you know of?

Comment: @JamesP Oh I thought you were on a Mac. MSVC has its own quirks. I will modify the answer a bit later.